# Is there a way to start a torrent on my Android stick remotely?

Tags: remote-control, torrents

I have a Windows home computer with uTorrent installed. With the BitTorrent WebUi addon to Firefox I am able to start downloads from my office computer.

I am planning on buying an Android stick, is there an app combination that can do the same? So I browse from my **Android** tablet, find a good magnet to download, do something not too complicated, and the **Android stick** starts to download it?

Comment: [uTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utorrent.client) has an Android app - will it not do the job?  The torrents are downloaded in your Android device and not in computer though.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I want to be able to start a download on device A from device B. I know how to do this on Windows, but is it possible on Android?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Torrent Manager](http://de.appbrain.com/app/torrent-manager/com.jpsfs.torrentmanager):

> Torrent Manager allows you to take control of your remote uTorrent, Vuze / Azureus, Transmission and Deluge clients. With this app you will be able to list, add, remove, start, stop and manage the queue order all your torrents from your remote desktop.

Other, similar alternatives are e.g. [TorrentToise](http://de.appbrain.com/app/torrenttoise/net.torrenttoise.free) and <strike>[Remote Transmission](http://de.appbrain.com/app/remote-transmission/com.neogb.rtac) (Transmission is a torrent client on Linux, so this is not for you)</strike>. Find more on AppBrain (or Google "Tiles" Play) by following their related apps ;)

Comment: It is not clear from their description, but both Torrent Manager and TorrentToise seem to be able to control windows clients only. I want to control an Android torrent client from another Android device.

Comment: @András, please check the related links from the apps' pages. App recommendation requests are off topic at ASE, so we are already in a kind of "gray zone" here ;)

Comment: I asked for a solution for my problem. You recommended some apps, I pointed out that they solve a different problem. I belive I remained on-topic.

Comment: This is not a valid answer to the question.

Comment: There is no native solution that ships with Android. So all that remains is to [check torrent apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=torrent) whether they offer the required feature, sorry. A good chance might be [Servers Ultimate Pack B](http://www.appbrain.com/app/servers-ultimate-pack-b/com.icecoldapps.serversultimate.packb), which offers a Torrent downloader client as well as Torrent tracker server. I didn't try it myself, so no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the solution wasnt possibly in `13. Currently you can install [utorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utorrent.client&hl=en) on your TV box and use [Transdrone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.transdroid.lite&hl=en) to control it. It works pretty well.